# How can I run a shell script as a setup file in Jest?

Tags: shell, jestjs, yarnpkg, end-to-end

Something like this. The goal is to start and stop my test server as part of the jest setup so I can do end to end testing with a single command.

```js
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/TestScript.sh"]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will answer this myself for anyone in the future who is trying to solve the same problem as me.

Jest config has `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` options. This script will be run once at the beginning of all tests.

```
"jest": {
  "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/jestGlobalSetup.js"
}
```

In node, you can use the `child_process` API to run shell scripts from a js file.
I ran mine like this in my setup file.

```js
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import cwd from 'cwd';

export default async function setup() {
  process.stdout.write('Starting Server');

  // Run this command in shell.
  // Every argument needs to be a separate string in an an array.
  const command = 'foreman';
  const arguments = [
    'start', 
    '-p', 
    '3000', 
    '-f', 
    'Procfile.test',
  ];
  const options = { 
    shell: true, 
    cwd: cwd() 
  };

  const server = spawn(
    command, 
    arguments,
    options,
  );

  // Then I run a custom script that pings the server until it returns a 200.
  await serverReady();
}
```

Comment: Could you share how you implement the `serverReady()` please? I am new to javascript :'[

Comment: Here's a gist https://gist.github.com/jeremygottfried/9622767fb475d50803a8e8aa1aee3e07

Answer (score 1):

you have to configure the globalSetup option in your jest.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  globalSetup: "<rootDir>/jestGlobalSetup.js",
  ...
};
```

then create the jestGlobalSetup.js file as following:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

module.exports = async function() {
    const myShellScript = exec('./TestScript.sh');//or run any other shell command

    myShellScript.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        // do whatever you want here with data
    });
    myShellScript.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.error(data);
    })
}
```